# Python Process time always returning a huge number even though it runs like normal?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is the code.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count

def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while count< num:
        count +=1


def main():
    a = Process(target=counter, args=(100000000,))
    a.start()

    a.join()

    print("finished in", time.perf_counter(), "seconds")





if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the return in the terminal.

finished in 808748.985729608 seconds

The program is completed in around 4 to 5 secs but returns this huge number every time?
Could someone help explain if I Did something wrong or a setting that may need to be changed. It is on a Mac if that matters.

Comment: You're using the `perf_counter()` function wrongly.  The number it returns is **not** the elapsed seconds since the program began.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture a start time and and end time and subtract.  The number by itself is meaningless (something like time since the OS booted):

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
a.start()
a.join()
print("finished in", time.perf_counter() - start, "seconds")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Weird as the code is from a direct follow along and word for word but doesn't include the start variable, and you see the correct return on their terminal. Functionally it worked no different it was just the difference in seconds. But it does make since why it would return the huge number if it is referencing the time epoch. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The `time.perf_counter` has unknown reference point, so you need to take the difference between two calls, one at the start, and one at the end as follows:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count

def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while count< num:
        count +=1


def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    a = Process(target=counter, args=(100000000,))
    a.start()

    a.join()

    print("finished in", time.perf_counter()-start, "seconds")

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```